# Syntax error: keyword can't be an expression with the function "Con"?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, con

From [How can I reclassify an integer raster to a float raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78245/how-can-i-reclassify-an-integer-raster-to-a-float-raster), I would like to reclassify an integer raster "cpraster3.tif" to a float raster.
For example, I would like to reclassify "Value" = 1 into 0.27, 
"Value" = 2 into 1.00 ...

Here is my code:

```
test_reclass = Float(Con(("cpraster3.tif", "Value" = 1, 0.27, Con("cpraster3.tif", "Value" = 2, 1.00, Con("cpraster3.tif", "Value" = 3, 2.9, Con("cpraster3.tif", "Value" = 4, 2.94, Con("cpraster3.tif", "Value" = 5, 5.37, Con("cpraster3.tif", "Value" = 6, 10.35, Con("cpraster3.tif", "Value" = 7, 16.49, Con("cpraster3.tif","Value" = 7, 22.08, 0.0)))))))))
```

But I have this error message:

> Failed to run script - syntax error - keyword can't be an expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `==` which is the equality operator, not a single `=` which is the assignment operator (i.e `a = 1` assigns the value `1` to the variable `a`). You can also shorten your expression by having the comparison as the first argument and dropping the `Value` field.

E.g:

```
test_reclass = Float(Con("cpraster3.tif" == 1, 0.27, Con("cpraster3.tif" == 2, 1.00, Con("cpraster3.tif == 3, 2.9, Con("cpraster3.tif" == 4, etc...
```

All those nested `Con` functions are quite unwieldy though. Have you considered using the [`Reclassify`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sr000000.htm) function instead?